# POST Method missing in 'Allowed' Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

This is what is showing when I go the rest framework page in my web browser

```
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
```

My model.py is as follows:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    title =  models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

These are my serializers.py :

```
class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = '__all__'
```

Lastly these are my views

```
class NotesViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = NoteSerializer
    queryset = Note.objects.all()
```

Comment: show the `urls.py` and the details of the entire request you make.

Answer (score 0):

you should add some function to work with the post request.
I might be mistaken but as far I know you need to define "post" and/or "update", "partial_update", "destroy" for making changes to the data, these are not pre defined.
You could use a [generic view set](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#generic-views) for default implementations.

[These are the viewset actions (documentation)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions)

Comment: This is not the case for a `ModelViewSet`, which implements these with the serializer: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/viewsets.py#L235

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info., it cleared up a lot of things